# How can I reset my SoC from cmm script using RISC-V trace32 debugger. I don't have TRST or SRST serial lines connected to SoC

Tags: emulation, riscv, trace32, lauterbach, vlsi

My cmm script is something like this :

..start of cmm script

""GTL config and GTL connect""
""some JTAG.SHIFT operations""

JTAG.PIN DISable

system.mode prepare        ;Need a reset here. I am trying this to reset my SoC

WAIT 10.MS                 ;this WAIT command is not working, no 10ms delay observed

system.down
system.mode prepare

...end of cmm script

Answer (score 0):

The normal approach to reset your RISC-V from the debugger without having a dedicated reset line is the following:

```
SYStem.Option.ResetMode NDMRST  
SYStem.Up
```

`SYStem.Option.ResetMode NDMRST`configures TRACE32 to perform all system resets via the ndmreset bit of the dmcontrol debug register in the RISC-V debug module (so without physical SRST pin).

`SYStem.Up` is then actually performing the reset before it connects the debugger with the core. You can also call SYStem.Up from up-state, just to reset your system.

However it looks like, you want to do the reset in prepare-state or even down-state. I guess you should contact the Lauterbach support on how to do that.

Comment: Is it possible to reset not just core but complete SoC from the debugger?

Comment: That depends a lot on your actual SoC. For the description of `SYStem.Option.ResetMode` see https://www.lauterbach.com/pdf/debugger_riscv.pdf